# Local angularjs code not woking in HTTP loaded HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I used Angularjs HTTP to load some PHP file to main page. But when I loaded this file, main page angularjs script are not working to loaded file.

Main Page Script Code:

```
$scope.biload = function() {
    $scope.bidata = "<p class='text-xs-center'><i class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-fw'></i>  රැදී සිටින්න..</p>";
    $http.post("/user/users_data/about/bidata.php",{"type": "get", "user":"<?php echo $_GET['u']; ?>"})
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.bidata = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data);

    }, function(error) {


    });


};

$scope.bieditor = false;

$scope.bienable = function() {
    $scope.bistatus = "enabaling..";


    $scope.bieditor = true;
};
```

bidata.php file:

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <span  class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Text</span>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input class="" type="text" value="Artisanal kale" ng-hide="bieditor">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <span  class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Search</span>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input class="" type="search" value="How do I shoot web" ng-hide="bieditor">
  </div>
</div>
```

Main Page HTML Code:

```
<button type="button" class="btnb btnb-info waves-effect waves-light btnb-sm float-right" ng-hide="bieditor" ng-click="bienable()">aa</button>
```

I want to do when I click this button it is call bienable() function. Then two text boxes should be hide in bidata.php external file. But now these two text boxes are not hiding. When I put these two text box in main page. It is working.